# How do we show the gridline in GridLayout in Qt?

Tags: qt

I was wondering if there is an easy way to show the grid lines separating sections in a grid layout governed by the QGridLayout class.
The doc has been failing me so far but I still feel there is an easy way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in function for this. Unfortunately you'd have to implement your own grid line using QLine to border the widgets.